# What would cause erratic primary key incrementing?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project with a microsoft sql DB that is containerized. I recently noticed that whenever I restart the project the next time I create an object it's primary key field is skipping anywhere from 900-1000 values. I am not really sure what information may be relevant to this issue. But here is a simple example. I have a simple model that is using the default autofield django automatically creates.

```
# models.py
class Contractor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        db_column="first_name", max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="First Name"
    )
```

I bring up the project...
`docker-compose -f local.yml up`
navigate to the view, create a new contractor and hit submit. The new Contractor will be created with its id=1. Then if I restart the project and create an additional Contractor, it will be created with an id=1002. I am confident this issue has nothing to do with my form as this happens for multiple different models and it happens whether I am using a form, or I am manually creating the object with `Contractor.objects.create()`.
I can explicitly pass an increment function to the id field and generate the correct id myself but that feels hacky. It only happens for the first object of each model that is created after restarting. Any additional object beyond the first increments by 1 as expected. Why are my autofield increments skipping a bunch of ids when I restart my project?

Comment: Why do you care?  The id should be an opaque token.

Comment: @TimRoberts I would prefer the increments to be consistent. At the very least I would like to understand what I have done to alter the incrementing. Why would I not care about something happening that I do not intend or expect? Ignoring erratic behavior you don't understand is not really an effective way to solve problems.

Comment: This is a common database misconception.  If you CARE about the value of the ID, then you need to SET the value of the ID, and not rely on undefined behavior.  Django may be doing database operations on startup that cause records to be created or deleted.

Comment: @TimRoberts It is not just spontaneously generating a value in a completely undefined way. The behavior must be defined somewhere And it is clearly being effected by the stopping and starting of the project because I can create thousands of objects and they all increment as expected except for the very first one after restart.

Comment: @TimRoberts If you are suggesting setting the ID myself is better practice than relying on djangos auto incrementing that is fine. But I would still like to know what is affecting the way the auto fields are incrementing. So you are saying it could be creating 1000 entries on startup and then deleting them... And thats causing it to skip those 1000 ids? Why would it create 1000 objects just to delete them?

Comment: I also noticed this thing with mssql. For the first time, I thought I might have done something horrible in my code that caused this issue. then reset it and checked the code but found nothing wrong, Then it happened again. Don't know the reason though!

Comment: @HemalPatel Interesting. I may have found a possible explanation if you care to know. Apparently mssql servers cache identity values and some of the assigned values can be lost when you restart the server. According to Microsoft's docs you should generate your IDs in your application if gaps aren't acceptable. You can search "identity jump mssql" and find some better explanations than I can give.

Comment: Sure will love to hear, Thanks for the info! Will take a look. :)